# Regularity of conformal maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

In order to define what it means for a map $f \colon \Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ to be conformal, it is sufficient to require that $f$ is everywhere differentiable. Does conformality automatically implies that $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$ (hence real-analytic, see below)?

By complex analysis, we know the answer is positive when $n=2$.

In higher dimensions, [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)) characterizes conformal maps as Möbius transformations, but it is stated for $f \in W^{1,n}$ in Wikipedia. Is it known whether it also holds when $f$ is assumed everywhere differentiable?

Comment: Can one retinterprete the concept of conformality in terms of certain elliptic PDE? hence regularity would imply real analyticity? In dimension 2 it is CR equation, an elliptic PDE.

Comment: Can one retinterprete the concept of conformality in terms of certain elliptic PDE? hence regularity would imply real analyticity? In dimension 2 it is CR equation, an elliptic PDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Let $n\geq 3.$ Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb R^n,$ and let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ be a function having a pointwise derivative $Df(x)$ everywhere satisfying $(Df)^T(Df)=g(x)I$ with $g(x)>0.$ Then $f$ is continuously differentiable.

By the [inverse function theorem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/), $f$ is a local homeomorphism. By shrinking $\Omega$ we can assume $f$ maps $\Omega$ homeomorphically to $f(\Omega),$ and that $\Omega$ and $f(\Omega)$ are bounded.
Note $$\|Df\|^2=c_ng(x)=c_n\det(g(x)I)^{1/n}=c_n|\det Df(x)|^{2/n}$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is Frobenius norm, and $c_n$ is a constant depending on $n.$
By the change of variables formula ([proof sketch](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59105/is-the-image-of-a-null-set-under-a-differentiable-map-always-null)), $$\int_\Omega |\det Df(x)|\;dx=\mu(f(\Omega))<\infty.$$
So $f\in W^{1,n}(\Omega,\mathbb R^n)$ and you can use the $W^{1,n}$ result you mentioned.

Comment: Beautiful. Just to be sure, the point is that the integral is also equal to the $L^n$ norm of $Df$ (up to a constant)?

Comment: @seub: yes, $\|Df\|^n$ is integrable, so $Df$ is in $L^n.$

Comment: @seub Note that this answer assumes that $df$ is invertible at every point. Some people allow the differential to degenerate in their definition of conformal maps.

Comment: @AsafShachar I am not aware of this convention. As far as I am concerned, a conformal map is an angle-preserving map. In other words it is a map whose derivative at any point is a linear similarity. It does not make sense to me to include maps having critical points.